# Magit checkout hunk / revert hunk

Tags: emacs, magit

File contents in HEAD commit:

```
A
B
C
D
```

After I modify the file, the contents is:

```
A
A2
B
C
D
D2
```

If I would like to revert the change at line 2 (A2), how can I do this with magit? So the result would have the contents be:

```
A
B
C
D
D2
```

Answer (score 8):

The term used by Magit is "discard". Like e.g. "stage" it is considered an "apply variant". <kbd>k</kbd> discards the "thing at point". If there is a region that begins inside a hunk and ends inside the same hunk, then it is a "hunk-internal region". If there is such a selection, then the various apply-variant commands operate on the region's content instead of the complete section.

This is documented in [Staging and Unstaging](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Staging-and-Unstaging.html) and [Applying](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Applying.html). It is also covered in the [Getting Started](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Getting-Started.html) part of the manual. You might want to give the documentation a chance.

What you have to do, boils down to this: goto `A2`, type <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> followed by <kbd>k</kbd>.

Comment: I'm using Spacemacs so that `k` keybinding does not seem to exist. If I activate a mark (C-SPC), and then execute `magit-discard` I get an error message of `Wrong type argument: arrayp, nill`.

I have not verified this on vanilla emacs / magit so perhaps it's a Spacemacs issue?

Comment: Discard in Spacemacs is `x`